# How to obtain Laplace transform of {f(t-a)U(t-b)}

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, laplace-transform, differential

$f(t)=g(t-10)U(t-15)-g(t-10)U(t-20)$

The above $f(t)$ contains terms of the form $g(t-a)U(t-b)$, where $a$ doesn't equal $b$. Describe the form that $L\{f(t-a)U(t-b)\}$ takes. [Hint: The formula for $L\{g(t)U(t-a)\}=e^{-as}L\{g(t+a)\}$

Answer (score 1):

$$Lf(t) = \int_0^\infty e^{-st}f(t)dt$$

$$L\{g(t-a)U(t-b)\}= \int_0^\infty e^{-st}(g(t-a)U(t-b))dt\\
= \int_b^\infty e^{-st}g(t-a)dt
= \int_{b-a}^\infty e^{-s(v+a)}g(v)dv
= e^{-sa}\int_{0}^\infty e^{-sv}g(v)U(b-a)dv
=  e^{-sa}\left(Lg(t)-\int_{0}^{b-a} e^{-sv}g(v)dv\right)
$$

Thus 
$$L\{g(t-10)U(t-15)-g(t-10)U(t-20)\} =\\ 
e^{-10s}\left(Lg(t)-\int_{0}^{5} e^{-sv}g(v)dv\right)
-e^{-10s}\left(Lg(t)-\int_{0}^{10} e^{-sv}g(v)dv\right)=\\
e^{-10s}\left(\int_{0}^{10} e^{-sv}g(v)dv-\int_{0}^{5} e^{-sv}g(v)dv\right)=\\
e^{-10s}\int_{5}^{10} e^{-sv}g(v)dv
$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $L\{ g(t-10)U(t-15)\}=e^{-15s}g(t-10+15)=e^{-15s}L\{g(t+5)\}$

and $L\{ g(t-10)U(t-20)\}=e^{-20s}g(t-10+20)=e^{-20s}L\{g(t+10)\}$

Alternatively, the given function is:

$f(t)=g(t-10), 15\le t\le 20$

Then, using standard definition $L\{f(t)\}=\int_{15}^{20} e^{-st}g(t-10)dt$